# Convert "Opportunity" to "Quotation" error in ODOO / OpenERP

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, openerp-8, odoo-8

I am developing mobile application for ODOO / OpenERP website in iOS.
I want to convert Opportunity to Quotation in ODOO mobile application ("Convert To Quotation").
For that i am using Model as: **"crm.make.sale"**
and method as: **"makeOrder"**

I choose to use above model and method by enabling developer mode. As shown in below screenshot[image]

Below are the input parameters for XMLRPC web-service call:

```
(
Database name,
1,
Password,
crm.make.sale,
makeOrder,
{
    id = 21;
    "partner_id" = 12;
}
)
```

But for above web-service call i am getting error as follow:

```
invalid input syntax for integer: "partner_id"
LINE 2: ...                     WHERE "crm_make_sale".id IN ('partner_i...
```

Where does i am doing wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This might fix your error:

```
(Database name, 1, Password, crm.make.sale, makeOrder, { 'id': 21; 'partner_id': 12;})
```